# is there a way to count logical lines of code of java script file

Tags: javascript

Can we find out logical lines of code of a javascript file?
I got a feedback from one of the review tool that JS should not have more than 100 LLOC, so would like to validate first how many LLOC code are there in JS file.

Comment: What's a logical line of code?

Comment: A line that is functional, not empty space or comments.

Comment: Has that *Review tool* ever looked at the jQuery Source? It has 9211 LOC - and guess what: Working perfectly fine... Statements like this are None-sence, because you can squeeze everyting into one line, if you like. Don't waste your time with *that* tool...

Comment: @dognose Yes. 100 line of logical codes is not really that much, tbf.

Answer (score 0):

It may be too heavy for you, but I use Plato (https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) to check things like this.  If you install that and then run it against a directory of JS files it will report back on all sorts of things.

It needs node.js and a few other bits but it works well.

Comment: this is nice plugin.. I got it working but unfortunately it considers Logical lines of code = Source lines of code, I only want LLOC and not source line of code.

Comment: Then I don't know, Plato does a lot for what it costs ($0), and I would take the review tool you mentioned that throws arbitrary limits at you like that with  a pinch of salt.  I use Plato to try to keep each js file I write down to under 400 SLOC, if it gets bigger than that I try to split it out as it is probably doing too much.  Some people would allow more, some less - it's a personal choice really.